# can any one tell me what the problem with this group chat app please

Tags: java, android, android-studio, chat

I'm trying to create a group chat app but when clicking on the send button, the message does not send. Please can anyone tell me what is wrong with my group chat app?

Here is the mainactivity xml file :

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/rvmessage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#147A18"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Enter message"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="#FF5722" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#A5DD64"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

it is item message xml file :

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/l1Message"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:text="  Random text"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"

                />





        </LinearLayout>


     </LinearLayout>
   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

here mainActivity java class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
DatabaseReference messagedb;
FirebaseDatabase database;
MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
List<Message> messages;
RecyclerView rvMessage;
EditText enterMess;
ImageButton imagebtn;

User u;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}

private void init()
{
   // fAuth     = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    database  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    enterMess = findViewById(R.id.message);
    rvMessage = findViewById(R.id.rvmessage);
    imagebtn  = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imagebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    messages =new ArrayList<>();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
// Initialize Firebase Auth

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final FirebaseUser curruser =fAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(curruser != null) {
    u.setUid(curruser.getUid());
    u.setEmail(curruser.getEmail());
    database.getReference("Users").child(curruser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            u=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            u.setUid(curruser.getUid());
            AllMethods.name= u.getName();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    messagedb = database.getReference("messages");
    messagedb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
            message.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            messages.add(message);
            displayMessages(messages);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
            message.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}}

private void displayMessages(List<Message> messages)
{
    rvMessage.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    //  rvMessage.setHasFixedSize(true);
    messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MainActivity.this,messages,messagedb);
    rvMessage.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
}
```

}

and it is User java class :

```
  public class User {
String uid,name,email;

public User(){}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String toString() {
    return "uid ("+uid + '\''+
            ",name= "+name + '\''+
            ",email= "+email+ '\''+")";
}}
```

it is message java  class :

```
   public class Message {
   String message , name ,key;

   public Message(){}

   public Message(String message, String name, String key)
    {
    this.message=message;
    this.name=name;
    this.key=key;
   }

   public String getMessage() {
    return message;
   }

   public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
   }

   public String getName() {
    return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
   }

   public String getKey() {
    return key;
       }

     public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
   }

  @NonNull
  @Override
   public String toString() {
    return "Message ("+message + '\''+
            ",name= "+name + '\''+
            ",key= "+key+ '\''+")";
     }

   }
```

it is allMethods java class :

```
   public class AllMethods {
  public  static String name ="";
  }
```

and manifest xml file :

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.examble.chatapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What code do you believe should execute when you click the button, and why do you believe that?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Comment: Kindly check what does onClick() method does.

Comment: This site is not intended to do your homework problems for you.  Homework problems are intended to show you how to use debugging tools as @Andreas points out.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

is blank, your not telling the `ImageButton` to do anything once it is clicked

Comment: but sir when putting if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(enterMess.getText().toString()))
        {
            Message message = new Message(enterMess.getText().toString(),u.getName());
            enterMess.setText("");
            messagedb.push().setValue(message);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "blanck message 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
Aa

the app crashed